# How to add quotes and commas in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a CSV file where I only need 1 Column Called "SerialNumber" I need to combine the text lines, remove any blank space, add each line in quotes and separate by comma.

So far I have multiple miles of code that work, but it adds quotes at the end and doesn't add quotes in the beginning.

```
$SerialList = import-csv .\log.csv | select -ExpandProperty Serialnumber | Out-File -FilePath .\Process.txt
(gc process.txt) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | set-content process.txt
gc .\process.txt | %{$_ -replace '$','","'} | out-file process1.csv
Get-Content .\process1.csv| foreach {
$out = $out + $_
}
$out| Out-File .\file2.txt
```

**Output:**

> SerialNumber
>
> 1234
>
> 1234
>
> 4567
>
> 4567

**Expected Output:**

> "1234","1234","4567","4567"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following (PSv3+):

```sh
(Import-Csv .\log.csv).SerialNumber -replace '^.*$', '"$&"' -join "," > .\file2.txt
```

- `(Import-Csv .\log.csv).SerialNumber` imports the CSV file and `.SerialNumber` uses [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) to extract the `SerialNumber` column values as an array.
- `-replace '^.*$', '"$&"'` encloses each array element in `"..."`.

  - [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) `^.*$` matches each array element in full.
  - Replacement expression `"$&"` replaces the element with what was matched (`$&`) enclosed in `"` chars. - for background, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375)
- `-join ","` joins the resulting array elements with `,` as the separator.